# Docker multistage: how to COPY built files between stages?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build, docker-copy

I'm beginner with Docker, and I'm trying to build an image in two stages, as explained here: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

> You can selectively copy artifacts from one stage to another

Looking at the examples given there, I had thought that one could build some files during a first stage, and then make them available for the next one:

```
FROM golang:1.7.3 AS builder
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go    .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

(Example taken from the above-linked page)

Isn't that what the `COPY app.go    .` and the `COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .` are supposed to do?

I probably have a complete misunderstanding of what is going on, because when I try to do something similar (see below), it seems that the `COPY` command from the first stage is not able to see the files that have just been built (I can confirm that they have been actually built using a `RUN ls` step, but then I get a `lstat <the file>: no such file or directory` error).

And indeed, most other information I can gather regarding `COPY` (except the examples in the above link) rather suggest that `COPY` is actually meant to copy files from the directory where the `docker build` command was launched, not from within the build environment.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM haskell:8.6.5 as haskell
RUN git clone https://gitlab+deploy-token-75:sakyTxfe-PxPHDwqsoGm@gitlab.pasteur.fr/bli/bioinfo_utils.git
WORKDIR bioinfo_utils/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-fastq/Haskell
RUN stack --resolver ghc-8.6.5 build && \
    stack --resolver ghc-8.6.5 install --local-bin-path .
RUN pwd; echo "---"; ls
COPY remove-duplicates-from-sorted-fastq .

FROM python:3.7-buster
RUN python3.7 -m pip install snakemake
RUN mkdir -p /opt/bin
COPY --from=haskell /bioinfo_utils/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-fastq/Haskell/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-fastq /opt/bin/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-fastq
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

And here is how the build ends when I run `docker build .` from the directory containing the Dockerfile:

```
Step 5/11 : RUN pwd; echo "---"; ls
 ---> Running in 28ff49fe9150
/bioinfo_utils/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-fastq/Haskell
---
LICENSE
Setup.hs
install.sh
remove-duplicates-from-sorted-fastq
remove-duplicates-from-sorted-fastq.cabal
src
stack.yaml
 ---> f551efc6bba2
Removing intermediate container 28ff49fe9150
Step 6/11 : COPY remove-duplicates-from-sorted-fastq .
lstat remove-duplicates-from-sorted-fastq: no such file or directory
```

How am I supposed to proceed to have the built file available for the next stage?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, apparently, I was mislead by the `COPY` step used in the first stage in the doc example. In my case, this is actually useless, and I can just `COPY --from=haskell` in my second stage, without any `COPY` in the first stage.

The following Dockerfile builds without issues:

```
FROM haskell:8.6.5 as haskell
RUN git clone https://gitlab+deploy-token-75:sakyTxfe-PxPHDwqsoGm@gitlab.pasteur.fr/bli/bioinfo_utils.git
WORKDIR bioinfo_utils/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-fastq/Haskell
RUN stack --resolver ghc-8.6.5 build && \
    stack --resolver ghc-8.6.5 install --local-bin-path .

FROM python:3.7-buster
RUN python3.7 -m pip install snakemake
RUN mkdir -p /opt/bin
COPY --from=haskell /bioinfo_utils/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-fastq/Haskell/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-fastq /opt/bin/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-fastq
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: Glad you're up and running but this doesn't help anyone else who's in need of artifacts from one stage in the next stage...

Comment: Where did haskell come from?  Your original question is about a golang app.

Comment: The golang app is the example I found on the internet. What I needed was a container able to compile Haskell code.

Comment: I have to do multiple copy command something like 
COPY --from=build /usr/local /usr/local
COPY --from=build /home/platform /home/platform
COPY --from=build /usr/lib /usr/lib

is it possible to inline these 3 lines. so that layer count can be reduced ?